# Unable to run Full indexing in backoffice 6.5

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

We are planning to migrate from HMC to Backoffice. I want all the data in HMC to be transferred to Backoffice. when I ran SOLR Full indexing but I am below getting Issue.
ERROR [Thread-6784] (00011GS2) [BackofficeIndexerStrategy] Executing indexer worker as an admin user failed:
ERROR [Thread-645] (00011HJD) [BackofficeIndexerStrategy] Executing indexer worker as an admin user failed:
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/01/13 09:54:59.310 |  de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.exceptions.IndexerException: de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.solr.exceptions.SolrServiceException: Could not check for a remote solr core [master_backoffice_backoffice_product_flip] due to Server refused connection at: http://Dev:8983/solr
Every time I get error. I had to restart my solr server.
Can someone please help me on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This might be an issue about SSL checks. You can try using disabling the SSL by adding

```
solrserver.instances.default.ssl.enabled=false
```

to your local.properties file. This should best only be used on your local development environment.

Or, you can try using https in your default solr server like https://localhost:8983/solr

Answer (score 0):

I am using sap hybris 2205, products displayes in front but, solrserver not working. i try this one also (backoffice.facet-facet conf.->siteindex->enter->finish) getting error.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).